# Why drop table when running unittests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I'm creating an api in Flask. Going through TestCases, i created an setUp and tearDown method

```bash
class TestFlaskBase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app()
        self.app.testing = True
        self.app_context = self.app.test_request_context()
        self.app_context.push()
        self.client = self.app.test_client()
        self.app.db.create_all()
    
    def tearDown(self):
        self.app.db.drop_all()
```

I really don't know why i have to drop flush my db to running unittests. Tried to search online but didnt get a real answer.

Comment: Unit test should always work with a clean set of data. if you didnt tear down your data from the table when your next unit test ran the previous data in the table could contaminate it. or you might end up writting unit tests that rely on data create by other unit tests. this is an antipattern as unit tests should be able to run in isolation and in any order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running unit tests, it's important to start with a clean slate each time, to ensure that the tests are not affected by previous test runs.

This includes dropping database tables, to reset the database to its initial state.